# JUnit testing gwt web app with 2 modules

Tags: eclipse, gwt, junit, smartgwt, smartclient

I am currently using gwt 2.3 and smartgwtpower 2.5 nightly and using Eclipse on Linux. My web app is using common code, developed in house, and packaged to a jar called commonsmartgwt.jar. In this jar is the entry point class and has its own gwt.xml file. In my web app's gwt.xml file I inherit from the entry point class

```
    <inherits
    name="common.code.Common"/>
```

and I use the entry point common.code.client.Common as my web app's entry point. All my classes in my web app extend classes in the common code. Compilation and running works
fine but when I try to run a test using eclipse method Run As > GWT Junit Test, I get the following error. 
    Unable to find common/code/Common.gwt.xml on your classpath; could be a typo,
    or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source. 
If I create the folder common/code/ under classes and extract the .gwt.xml file from the commonsmartgwt.jar and put it in that directory, I get a different error.

```
    'my.package.client.MyFirstTest' was not found in module
    'common.client.Common'; no compilation unit for that type was seen
```

Is there a way to Unit test this application. Please let me know if my situation is not clear. What if I moved the entry point from the common code to my web app? I tried following the instructions here: [Error resolution][1]

```
  [1]: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/testing_gwt_applications "Link"
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the incorrect module name returning in the getModuleName test method.